# Proper & complete way to declare website graphical-logo microdata

Tags: html, image, microdata, graphical-logo

I looked for the proper way to declare logo image in HTML5 with microdata

in this address: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146861?hl=en also by clicking **Microdata (recommended) sublink** it can be seen that

`<img alt="logo" src="http://www.example.com/logo.png" />`

became

`<img itemprop="logo" src="http://www.example.com/logo.png" />`

So **my 1st question is** why they omitted `alt` tag. What if I code as below. Technically it'll be still correct, right? Or is there any conflict between `alt` tag and `itemprop="logo"`?

`<img itemprop="logo" alt:"Image with a sea blue background and tale character Little Black Fish jumps out of the water" src="http://www.example.com/logo.png" />`

**my 2nd question is**
I have a complex, great-in-size logo and with my logo image I want to tell to search engines the story of my logo. (the symbols, their meanings, creators of that symbols etc.)

So which micro data tag I need with which syntax to achieve my aim if any? thanks

Comment: Note that in your example it says `alt:` instead of `alt=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s a very bad example from Google:

1. The `alt` content "logo" is usually not appropriate for a logo (unless the company/etc. is *named* "logo").
2. An `img` with Microdata’s `itemprop` attribute still needs an `alt` attribute.

There are no conflicts between `alt` and `itemprop`. Your example with both of these attributes is fine.

---

To describe your logo in greater detail, you would need to find an appropriate Microdata vocabulary. If you want to use the schema.org vocabulary, the type [`ImageObject`](http://schema.org/ImageObject) is probably the best you can get currently.

You could also use the [`longdesc` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-longdesc/) ([currently](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-html-longdesc-20130716/) a *Working Draft*) "to link descriptions to images in HTML5 content".